# Publishing an AVRO messages to Kafka via Kafka REST

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

We have deployed Confluent Platform 6.0 in our Kubernetes cluster. I have created a Kafka topic "test-topic-1" via Kafka REST api. Now I'm trying to publish a simple AVRO message to this topic.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://kafka-rest-master.k8s.hip.com.au/topics/test-topic-1' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json' \
--data-raw '{"value_schema":{"type":"record","name":"User","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string"}]},"records":[{"value":{"name":"testUser"}}]}'
```

I get a 500 error response for this request,

```
{"error_code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error"}
```

When I check the logs of the kafka rest pod, I can see the following error,

> ERROR Request Failed with exception
> (io.confluent.rest.exceptions.DebuggableExceptionMapper)
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
> at [Source:
> (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream);
> line: 1, column: 17] (through ref erence chain:
> io.confluent.kafkarest.entities.v2.SchemaTopicProduceRequest["value_schema"])
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1445)

Am I following the correct steps to publish an AVRO message to a newly created Kafka topic? If so what could be the problem here?

Comment: I think value_schema is a a String representation of the schema, so it should be between " and with the various escapes. Example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591443/posting-avro-serialised-data-using-kafka-rest-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

your AVRO schema definition is wrong. It should be defined as the following

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "recordName",
  "namespace": "namespace",
  "doc": "description",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "key",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

OR

```
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "fiedName",
    "type": "string"
  },
]
```